# Generate/Create New Query Parameter in WSO2-AM Sequence

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I have a use case where create new set of query parameters(Say 4 new query parms) based on a query parameter come from request and send all query parameters(both newly created and old) into target server. How to achieve ? I have created a logic to split that query param come from request using Script Mediator and set into query param function like mc.setProperty("query.param.IndA", IndA);

```
<script function="restGET"
        key="conf:repository/resources/scripts/rest.js" language="js"/>
<header name="To" scope="default" value="http://localhost:8443/res/c/r/cust/0.0.1/e"/>
```

But this doesn't set in request and reached to end server. Is that anyway better way than this approach ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [REST_URL_POSTFIX](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/HTTP+Transport+Properties#HTTPTransportProperties-REST_URL_POSTFIXREST_URL_POSTFIX) property to append values to the target endpoint. Please refer the [example](https://jenananthan.wordpress.com/2015/09/22/wso2-esbapim-add-query-parameter-to-endpoint/) which uses that property.

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by @pubci is correct. Here I am adding some additional info on reading query parameter from request- To read the query parameter from  the request no need to have script mediator , you can just use synapse xpath variable $url [1]. You can find a sample here[2]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Synapse+XPath+Variables#SynapseXPathVariables-$trp

[2] https://jenananthan.wordpress.com/2015/09/22/how-to-read-dynamic-query-parameter-in-esbapim-synapse/

Comment: Thanks for your reply !! I have to use Script Mediator in order to manipulate the original request query parameter array values to split. But, i have done in script mediator send back to sequence as variables. Continued next comment since the limit.

Comment: And included the  REST_URL_POSTFIX property. But, when include HTTPEndpoint mediator in one of the case in the Switch..Case mediator, I get, **unknown synapse configuration tag: <endpoint name="HTTPEndpoint"></endpoint>** as your recommendation. Why I could not include HTTP endpoint mediator. Note: each case have its own dynamic endpoints by using like <header name="To" scope="default" value="https://localhost:8443/xp/r/ce/rest/customer/0.0.1/s"/>